# Persisting spaCy import error: NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+

Tags: python, spacy, importerror, urllib3

I realize this is a recently common error, but none of the solutions I have found online helped me. I am trying to work with spaCy in Jupyter notebook and VScode on a Mac OS , but every time I try to import spacy, I get the following error:

```
NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020
  warnings.warn(
```

I tried

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

This didn't work so I then tried to downgrade urllib3 using

```
pip install urllib3==1.26.6
```

didn't work either. I tried using a virtual environment, also didn't work. I've been scouring the web trying to find a solution but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Update newer version released June 7, 2003    py -m pip install urllib3  or py -m pip install urllib3 --upgrade

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a spaCy issue, but an issue with the Python installation. You could try to install an older version of urllib3, for instance, I have a virtual environment with a recent version of spaCy 3.5 and urllib3 1.26.15, which works fine:

```
pip install urllib3==1.26.15
```

If that doesn't work, please confirm with pip show urllib3 that that version was indeed installed and what error you are getting. Another option would be to build or install a Python version that is built against OpenSSL 1.1.1 or newer.

```
I tried

brew install openssl@1.1
```

This will usually not work, because Homebrew installs openssl as a keg-only, meaning that the library is not visible, unless you explicitly link against it. Secondly, the SSL module links against libressl, which most likely has a different shared library version. Finally, the SSL module could have the library paths hardcoded (it does on my installation).

Comment: It should be two equal signs for pip install: `pip install urllib3==1.26.15`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to use the Python 'requests' HTTP library, same error message. The following steps got it working for me on Apple M1 Pro - Ventura 13.5.

**Install Homebrew (If not already):**

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Or via their new .pkg installer: [Homebrew 4.1.3](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases/tag/4.1.3)

**Add Homebrew to your PATH (I'm using bash):**

```
echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

**Install latest version of openssl:**

```
brew install openssl@3.0
```

**Make sure openssl is first in your path, since brew installs it as keg-only.**

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3.0/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/<username>/.bash_profile
```